# WHY for loop php output this result?

Tags: php

I don't understand for loop in PHP,

```
`$total = 0;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $total += $i;
    
}
echo $total;`
```

normally equal an 11 no ? he output me 55, but for python when you execute similar code with "while loop"

```
total = 0

while total <= 10:
    total+=1
print(total)
```

output me 11

please someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **PHP CODE**

In the PHP code, you get the sum of 1 to 10 numbers using for loop.
That is,
0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55

Because you have initially given 0 to the $total variable in the PHP code. Then you have given 1 to the $i variable in the for loop and you keep increasing the loop 1 by 1 until the value in $i is less than 10 or equal 10. Then the value in $i is added to the value in the $total.

**1st Iteration**
$total = total + 1

**2nd Iteration**
$total = total + 2

**3rd Iteration**
$total = total + 3

.
.
.
.
.

**10th Iteration(because $i <= 10)**
$total = total + 10

Then exit the loop and now $total = 55

## **PYTHON CODE**

In the python code you have also using while loop and 0 is assigned to the total variable at the beginning of the code.

In this case all you have to do is increase the value of the total variable by 1

That is,

**1st Iteration**
total = total + 1

**2nd Iteration**
total = total + 1

**3rd Iteration**
total = total + 1

.
.
.
.
.

**10th Iteration(because total <= 10)**
total = total + 1

Then exit the while loop and now total = 11

****These two codes are not the same!!!****

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP and python code is not equivalent. In python you just add 1 each time in the loop. However in the PHP you are adding the value to the $i value, which of course keeps increasing every time - i.e. 1+2+3+3+5...etc.

You could write

```
$total += 1;
```

or just

```
$total++;
```

instead and it would work the same as the python. But then again that makes `$total` redundant because it just has the same value as `$i`, and you don't really need two variables doing the same job.

Or you could write a `while` loop to be more directly equivalent to the python:

```
$total = 0;

while ($total <=10) {
  $total++;
}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply because in php code you are incrementing it with `i` as:`total+i`
if total wore intially zero `0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10`==`55`
while in python you are incrementing it with `total+1` not `i`
so each time only `+1` incrementaion
so `0+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1`=`11`

Comment: if you want similar thing in your php script just replace `i` with`1`